# setting an accuracy timer for gps app in android

Tags: android, timer, gps

i'm new to coding so please be gentle

i have an gps app that i want to alter its accuracy .
i want it too only log when it has a strong signal, not signal that comes and goes.
below 20 plots perfectly well but when signal is a bit in and out it will plot extremes

so what i was thinking was if the accuracy was say below 10 for a 10 seconds then start logging, and if over 30 for 30 seconds stop logging.
but set accuracy to 20 while logging.
i can work out how to use the simple command of
if(currentAccuracy <= 20.0)
but how would i implement the timer section
all i can find on timers is count down clocks

it is currently this

public boolean shouldLog(float currentAccuracy) { if(currentAccuracy <= 20.0) return true; else return false; } –

im sure this is simple if you know your way around but im at a loss

thanks for your help

Comment: public boolean shouldLog(float currentAccuracy) {

           if(currentAccuracy <= 20.0)
               return true;
            else
               return false;
        }

Comment: Please edit your post instead placing code samples as comments.